# Changing a 2D array into a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have an array that has 8450 rows and 16 columns. I want to feed these data points into an RNN with each 50 points being an entry. So 0-49 is z=0, and 1-50 is z=1 and so forth. The columns need to remain unchanged so that I can still have the same data in each z axis entry. So basically I am taking every chunk of 50 points and moving it into a third axis. Is there simple way to do this python? I tried the reshape but I may not have been doing it correctly. Currently the data is in a pandas dataframe.

```
points = 50
for i in range(len(data_prepped_dataframe)-points):
     x_data = data_prepped_dataframe.iloc[i:i+points,:]
```

So far I have this but all this does is give me the last 50 points in the data set. I tried adding indexes to the x_data term but that threw an error

I tried

```
x_data[:,:,i] = data_prepped_dataframe.iloc[i:i+points,:]
```

but the error said x_data wasn't defined.

Comment: `x_data = [data_prepped_dataframe.iloc[i:i+points,:] for i in range(len(...) - points)`?

Comment: close, if you add np.array(...) and enclose your suggestion in the ( ), I get a 1x50x16 array, which is very close but the 1 dimension needs to have lots more. That still only gave me the last 50 rows of the whole dataset

Answer (score 0):

If you change the dataframe to an array using np.array() and then add .copy() at the end this will output the 3D array. Specifically in this case a (8400 x 50 x 16) array